# SVG in PPT( generated by Pptxgenjs) shown incorrectly when the PPT is opened in libreOffice

Tags: node.js, powerpoint, libreoffice, pptxgenjs

Pptxgenjs is able to add SVG images and generate PPT correctly. When this PPT is opened using Microsoft office, SVG images are shown properly. However, when this PPT is opened using libreOffice, SVG images are shown as invalid cross symbols as mentioned below.

[image: PPT in LibreOffice]

[image: PPT in MS Office]

- ENV: Windows 10
- LibreOffice Version 7

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the same SVG to a slide in LibreOffice? If it shows the same problem, you know that the problem is with LO and not your code. SVG as a format has a lot of features that may or may not be supported in a particular application. You may have come across one that PPT supports but LO does not.

Comment: @steverindsberb, Manually adding SVG to LibreOffice presentation works fine. However, the issue is with adding SVG programmatically using Pptxgenjs.

Comment: Understood. That at least proves that the SVG or LO's interpretation of it is not at fault. So next, what if you manually insert the SVG into PPT, save, then open the PPT in LO? In other words, is there something that PPT does with the SVG that's not compatible with LO?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Manually insert the SVG into MS PPT, save, then open the PPT in LO is also fine.

Comment: it seems then that Pptxgenjs is doing something that LibreOffice doesn't understand. Since I'm not a javascript user, I couldn't suggest anything further along those lines; sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Node.js](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/nodejs/) to add SVG images and other content to your presentations. You can evaluate this REST-based API  making 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to add an SVG image to a presentation using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```js
const cloud = require("asposeslidescloud")
const model = require("asposeslidescloud/model")
const fs = require("fs")

const slidesApi = new cloud.SlidesApi("client_id", "client_key")

const fileName = "example.pptx"
const imagePath = "image.svg"
const slideIndex = 1

// Create a picture frame for the SVG image with a specified size and position.
var pictureFrame = new model.PictureFrame()
pictureFrame.pictureFillFormat = new model.PictureFill()
pictureFrame.pictureFillFormat.svgData = fs.readFileSync(imagePath, "utf8")
pictureFrame.X = 20
pictureFrame.Y = 20
pictureFrame.Width = 300
pictureFrame.Height = 200

// Add the picture frame on the slide.
slidesApi.createShape(fileName, slideIndex, pictureFrame).then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
})
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.